# How to change name by default of permission in Django?

Tags: django, permissions

Help me to change the name of permissions of my app

The permissions of my app:

```
[] articles | article | Can add article
[] articles | article | Can change article
[] articles | article | Can delete article
```

I want to have the name of the permissions in spanish

```
Articulo - Puede cambiar articulo
Articulo - Puede eliminar artículo
Articulo - Puede crear articulo
```

## **EDIT:**

I have two opctions:

## 1. Create Middleware AdminLocaleURLMiddleware

## 2. Overwrite unicode method of Permission:

```
from django.utils import six
def permissions_new_unicode(self):
    nombre_clase = six.text_type(self.content_type)
    nombre_permiso = six.text_type(self.name)
    if 'Can delete' in nombre_permiso:
        nombre_permiso = nombre_permiso.replace('Can delete', 'Puede eliminar')
    elif 'Can add' in nombre_permiso:
        nombre_permiso = nombre_permiso.replace('Can add', 'Puede crear')
    elif 'Can change' in nombre_permiso:
        nombre_permiso = nombre_permiso.replace('Can change', 'Puede modificar')

    return u'%s - %s' % ( nombre_clase.title(), nombre_permiso)
```

**Replace the __unicode__ method in Permission Class**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
Permission.__unicode__ = permissions_new_unicode
```

Comment: Is your browser set to english?  The admin  backend will display in whatever language your browser is set to.

Comment: But only for translation of the labels, you must override __str__ method not __unicode__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to explicitly set language for django admin section use this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import translation


    class AdminLocaleURLMiddleware:

        def process_request(self, request):
            if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
                request.LANG = getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_LANGUAGE_CODE', settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
                translation.activate(request.LANG)
                request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.LANG
```

Then put somewhere in settings.py:

```
ADMIN_LANGUAGE_CODE='es'
```

and add middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   ...
    'utils.multilang.middleware.AdminLocaleURLMiddleware',
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

there is short but tricky answer. I wouldn't recommend to do this way neither reject that. but the solution is:
edit the `app_labeled_name` function decorated as `property` of this path: `path/to/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py` of `ContentType` class, to become like this:

```
@property
def app_labeled_name(self):
    model = self.model_class()
    if not model:
        return self.model
    return '%s | %s' % (apps.get_app_config(model._meta.app_label).verbose_name,
                        model._meta.verbose_name)
```

the trick is to use `apps.get_app_config(model._meta.app_label).verbose_name` instead of `model._meta.app_label`, so it would use the same `verbose_name` as whatever use set for your app in the `AppConfig` subclass of your app.

Comment: That path may exist on your computer but for many others it won't exist. if you want to provide a solution like this, either provide a way that can be done using subclasses / overrides or monkey patching.

Comment: yes, you're right but it is recommended for everyone to create a virtual environment for python in order to develop django, and nobody could develop django without installing it. the path is relative.

Comment: @Melvyn hello again, I've provided a new solution and a complete one. could you visit and tell me about that. [here](https://gist.github.com/mh-firouzjaah/2b490a53ab8cf576317935b09c5f945e)

Comment: That looks a lot better. You're not really using a signal here, but that's minor. You should probably handle and [unregister Permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.unregister) in case it's already registered.