# Django - Translate name of Permission model

Tags: django

I'm trying to translate the name of the permissions, but it does not work with this code. I do not get any error. Permissions are still in English, I want them to be in the language set in settings. Any idea what that might be?

```
# forms.py
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
class PermissionModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return '%s' % _(obj.name)

# settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

Comment: hello, could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419919/how-to-change-name-by-default-of-permission-in-django/66612707#66612707) answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to translate the name of the permissions manually. Some words like "Can" gettext_lazy can not translate, so I used the "replace" method to leave the language I want. Other words like "group" or "user" gettext_lazy can translate.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class PermissionModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    permissions_translated = [_(w).replace('Can', 'Pode').replace('add', 'adicionar').replace('change', 'alterar').replace('delete', 'excluir').replace('view', 'visualizar') for w in (obj.name).split()]
    return ' '.join(permissions_translated)
```

Comment: hi, could you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419919/how-to-change-name-by-default-of-permission-in-django/66612707#66612707).

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet can help you.

```
class RoleCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Permission.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={
            'class':'selectpicker widget border border-2 border-warning rounded bg-transparent'
        })
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets={
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class':'form-control widget border-warning rounded'
            })
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Filter permissions for tracking, traccar, and accounts apps
        tracking_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='tracking').exclude(content_type__model='geoeventsetting')
        traccar_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='traccar', content_type__model__in=['tcdevices', 'tcreports'])
        accounts_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='accounts',content_type__model__in=['useraccount'])
        auth_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label='auth',content_type__model__in=['group'])

        # Concatenate the filtered permissions and set them as the choices for the permissions field
        self.fields['permissions'].queryset = tracking_permissions | traccar_permissions | accounts_permissions |auth_permissions

        # Translate the permission names
        self.fields['permissions'].label_from_instance = self.label_permission_instance

    def label_permission_instance(self, obj):
        permission_name = obj.name


        permissions_translated =[w.replace('Can', 'Peut').replace('add', 'ajouter').replace('change', 'modifier').replace('delete', 'supprimer').replace('view', 'voir').replace('user', 'utilisateur').replace('tc', '').replace('devices', 'boitiers').replace('reports', 'rapports').replace('group', 'profil')   for w in permission_name.split()]
        return ' '.join(permissions_translated)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `__str__` method for the Permission model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def permission_string_method(self):
    names = self.name.split()
    operation_translated = ' '.join([
        _(w).replace('Can', str(_('Can')))
        .replace('add', str(_('add')))
        .replace('change', str(_('change')))
        .replace('delete', str(_('delete')))
        .replace('view', str(_('view')))
        .replace('log', '').replace('content', '').strip()
        for w in names[:-1]  # Exclude the last word (model name)
    ])
    return f"{operation_translated} | {self.content_type.name}"

Permission.__str__ = permission_string_method
```

and put your translations in django.po:

```
msgid "Can"
msgstr "Pode"
msgid "view"
msgstr "visualizar"
msgid "add"
msgstr "adicionar"
msgid "change"
msgstr "alterar"
msgid "delete"
msgstr "excluir"
```

don't forget to run `python manage.py compilemessages`